# meaning of a @ in /usr/lib/systemd/system .service name files

Tags: mysql, centos7, systemd

There is a mysql installed in a centos machine.

I am trying to modify the mysql service file so as to include a new "RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/mysqldata" line to ensure the disk where the mysql data resides is mounted before the mysql server starts.

But I have noticed there are two mysql.service files. One with an @ and other one without it.

```
[user@machine system]$ pwd
/usr/lib/systemd/system
[user@machine system]$ ls -l mysqld*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1614 mar 18  2017 mysqld.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1645 mar 18  2017 mysqld@.service
```

I do not know which are the difference between them, which one is used or why there are two of them.

Their content is practically the same.

```
[user@machine system]$ diff mysqld.service mysqld@.service
1c1
< # Copyright (c) 2015, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
---
> # Copyright (c) 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
35c35
< PIDFile=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
---
> PIDFile=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-%i.pid
44c44
< ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd
---
> ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd %I
47c47
< ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS
---
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-group-suffix=@%I --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-%i.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS
```

The status of the unit suggests me the one without the @ is being used. But I still wonder why there are two of them and their meaning.

```
[user@machine system]$ systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since jue 2017-09-21 09:57:05 CEST; 1h 40min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 1042 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 950 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1357 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─1357 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

sep 21 09:57:00 machine systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
sep 21 09:57:05 machine systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
```

Comment: keep in mind that you should not edit that file directly, but instead copy it into the similiar systemd folder structure in /etc/ to prevent it getting overwritten on the next update

Comment: The use of the  "@" character is documented in `man systemd.service`. Also see `man systemd.directives` for a full list of directives` and `man systemd.index` for a full list of systemd man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the the `@` has a special meaning in systemd.

Say we have a service called `echo@.service` with the following in it

```
ExecStart=/bin/echo %i
```

So if I do

```
systemctl start echo@1.service
```

I'd get `1` in the `journalctl`.

So `%i` in the service file gets replaced with anything after `@` when you start the service.

So it looks like in your case the `mysqld@.service` would be if you wanted to run multiple mysql servers on the same host.